# Seo Friendly Url Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, friendly-url

I am building an asp.net mvc 4 project and i have to make seo friendly url so when try like first  code it's working but second route map not working how can i fix that.

I want to url like `example.com/seo-url-nice`

```
  routes.MapRoute(
               "RecipeDetails",
               "recipe/{id}/{slug}",
               new { controller = "Recipe", action = "Details", slug = "" },
               new { id = @"^\d+$" });


   routes.MapRoute(
                "RecipeDetails",
                "{slug}",
                new { controller = "Recipe", action = "Details", slug = "" }
           );
```

Updated: Resolving code added.

```
 public ActionResult Details(string slug)
        {
            var recipe = _db.Recipes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SeoText == slug);

            if (recipe != null)
            {
                // Redirect to proper name
                if (slug != recipe.SeoText)
                    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Details", new { slug = recipe.SeoText });

                return View(recipe);
            }

            return RedirectToRoute("Index");
        }
```

I am trying to access recipe details

```
http://localhost:8777/apple-sponge-cake
```

Then got this error:

```
The constraint entry 'slug' on the route with URL '{slug}' must have a string value or be of a type which implements IRouteConstraint.
```

Comment: What url are you trying and how do you resolve slugs?

Comment: I updated my question please review

Comment: Does this exception occurs at application startup or when you acccess the url?